# Cannot pass the lighthouse audit for CRA PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

I am trying to build a PWA with CRA and ran into some issues. However, even though I have registered the user (`serviceWorker.register()` in index.js) and can store the files in cache storage and run it offline, I still cannot pass the audit and I get (I've built my web app already, so it's running in production mode):

> 1.`start_url` does not respond with a 200 when offline Unable to fetch start URL via service worker.
>
> 2.Current page does not respond with a 200 when offline
>
> 3.Does not register a service worker that controls page and `start_url`

Which in my opinion is caused by wrong `start_url`.

I have a `manifest.json` and `index.html` in public folder and `serviceWorker.js`, `index.js` inside the src folder (inside public). and I get `service-worker.js` and `manifest.json` in the build folder after I build the app.

I've tried changing the `start_url` to `"."` , `"index.html"`, `"/"` and some other options, but it did not change anything, still the same error.

### Edit

I am also getting this

[Network tab in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Empsy.png)

[Console in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tQpE.png)

Error in this line in `serviceWorker.js`:

> fetch(swUrl)

Seems like `service-worker.js`, `manifest.json` are not precached. This is weird, because from my understanding it should be precached automiatically. What is the solution here ?

Comment: Hi Tomas, Did you you end up finding any solution for this issue?